# Freezing Table columns and rows using only one table

Tags: php, html, scroll, html-table, freeze

I have a dynamic table which is filled from an Application.
My problem is that I need some way to freeze the first row and the first four columns BUT using only one table, obviously because I will be posting the table back again to the application.

My Current Table Code :

```
....
<form name="myform" method="post" action="test123.php" onsubmit="set_value();">
//this form is used to post back the data after user updates it.
<br /> 
<table align="center" id="dataTable">
<thead>
<tr class="header">
...
$arratt49 = (explode(',',$response49,-1)); //sending an array from application
$dayscounter = sizeof($arratt49);
$sizemon = strlen($month1);
if($sizemon > 0)
{
    echo "<th class='text ce6'>No.</th>";
    echo "<th class='text ce6'>Emp code</th>";
    echo "<th class='text ce6'>Name</th>";
    echo "<th class='text ce6'>Department </th>";
for($kkk=0;$kkk<$dayscounter;$kkk++)
    {
    echo "<th class='text ce7'>";
    echo $arratt49[$kkk];
    echo "</br>";
    echo $arratt49[$kkk+1];
    echo "</th>";
    $kkk = $kkk +1;
    }
}
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
....//Here goes the Body
for($k=0;$k<=$arrcnt;$k++)
    {   
                echo "<td class='text ce2'>";
                echo $counter;
                echo "</td>";                   
                echo "<td class='text ce2'><INPUT type='text' name='code[]' size = '8' readonly='true 'value='";
                echo $arratt[$k];
                echo "'";
                echo "</td>";
                echo "<td class='text ce2'><INPUT type='text' name='name[]' size = '40' readonly='true' value='";
                echo $arratt[$k+1];
                echo "'";
                echo "</td>";
                echo "<td class='text ce2'><INPUT type='text' name='dept[]' size = '12' readonly='true 'value='";
                echo $arratt[$k+2];
                echo "'>";
                echo "</td>";
```

Already tried :

[Big Four](http://www.imaputz.com/cssStuff/bigFourVersion.html) method

and also [This](http://meetselva.github.io/fixed-table-rows-cols/)


Any Good Ideas?
Again I  **CANNOT**  use more than one table method.

[image]

Comment: Can you use plugin datatables? http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/extras/FixedColumns/two_columns.html

Comment: @test1604 : thanks for the suggestion,i checked, the above method is working only with columns, i need to freeze 1 ROW, and 4 COLUMNS in the same table.

Comment: Do you need to freeze header + 1st row?

Comment: the header (or the 1st row + 4 first columns.

Comment: i uploaded a picture explaining the area that i want to freeze.

Comment: Look at this example http://coastworx.com/freezepanes_table_scroll.html

Comment: i checked that one already,but JavaScript code is using buttons for scrolling which is obviously will make it even harder for users to scroll.

Comment: I have edited datatables, look at this preview http://live.datatables.net/ijiqej/edit#preview

Comment: seems great,i will try to merge both code now and see what happen.
do you mind share the full code of this datatable above? (Including CSS files if possible)

Comment: If need to fix more rows, I think you can add these rows to the header, and whole header will be fixed on top of your table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use datatables plugin [FixedColumns](http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/extras/FixedColumns/two_columns.html), just set parameter "iLeftColumns" to the number of columns needed to be fixed from the left side of table. Header already fixed by default.

Comment: can you describe how i can use the plugin??

Comment: You can see examples and api, it very simple to use, just look through the sources http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/extras/ColReorder/fixedcolumns.html

Comment: I tried it,but seems there is some issue with JS file.
any how i moved to http://www.matts411.com/post/grid/
it works great,but i have small issue converting DOM to JSON.